# How to display projects location inside VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The 'Solution Explorer' in VS 2010 helps list all projects embedded into the current solution. I would like to view the project directory structure instead of just the project name.

For example, this is the content of 'Solution Explorer'

```
Solution 'xxx' (3 projects)
+ adapter
+ auto
+ constructor
```

I would like to see the folder structure of this solution as follows:

```
c:\chapter03\adapter
c:\shapter01\auto
c:\chapter08\constructor
```

For now, I can only get this information by looking into the project properties.

Is there an easy way that can reveal the project directory structure?

Comment: Do you mean the Properties (Alt+Enter), or Properties tab in the interface? The properties tab is the easiest way I can think of without doing something custom.

Comment: I just want to see the solution folder structure in an easy way.

Answer (score -1):

In **Solution Explorer**, right click on the solution and select from the context menu **Open Folder in Windows Explorer**.

Note, this is not in VS2010 itself but it shows the folder structure in Windows Explorer itself.